# What is the best translation for the noun "treat"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, comida, número-gramatical

A `treat` is

> something **special** that you do or buy for yourself or someone else
>
> <sub>[macmillandictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/treat_2)</sub>
>
> (US) something that tastes good and that is not eaten often
>
> <sub>[learnersdictionary](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/treat)</sub>

The examples given by learnersdictionary are the most interesting for this question:

- freshly baked **treats** [=goodies]
- cookies and other tasty **treats**
- She rewarded the dog with a **treat**.

When the dog receives that *treat*, is a sort of `premio` or `recompensa` (which goes implicit in the verb *rewarded* and might be redundant as such in a translation).

The "cookies and other tasty *treats*" can be misleading. Although is easy to associate `treats` with "dulces" it doesn't need to be the case. For example, "chorizo" is a treat for my family. Where we live *chorizo* is not impossible to find, but can be difficult (at least finding a good quality one) and thus, it is pricey. So chorizo is a treat for our family. We don't eat it often and when we do I cut just a few *rodajas* for the kid and it's something "special".

Probably many different things could be considered "treats" since, after all, with the usage of `treat` as a verb you could "*treat* yourself to a massage" or "take the kids to the water park as a special *treat*" (in which *treat* is more like an [*agasajo*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=145ieuM)).

It sounds weird to me, but maybe the proper translation for "chorizo is a treat for our family" would be

> El chorizo es una *chuchería* en nuestra familia
>
> El chorizo es una *golosina* en nuestra familia

because I always associated `chucherías` and `golosinas` as something sweet (candy-like), but maybe it doesn't need to be, since the definition of [golosina](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JJSPPh5) says that is "generally sweet" it it doesn't need to be.

What would be a good way of translating "treat" into Spanish, considering that we can understand it meaning as

> something that tastes good and that is not eaten often

Comment: There is also the usage (in a bar) "It's my treat" which I think is _te invito_

Comment: Iba a editar "cuchería" pero como lo has puesto dos veces me ha entrado la duda de si lo has escrito así a propósito ¿es un error?

Comment: @blonfu, no, tienes tú razón. La he puesto mal la primera vez y he debido de arrastrar el error con un copia-pega. Seguramente el corrector me la ha resaltado y yo he pensado que era porque estaba en español (mientras que el autocorrector estaba en inglés), sin darme cuenta de la errata.

Comment: Es similar a lo que conocemos en Chile como _[un engañito](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/enga%C3%B1ito)_: "Pequeño regalo, obsequio de poco valor económico, dado como muestra de amistad, retribución o cariño."

Answer (score 3):

En [Pons](https://en.pons.com/translate?q=treat&l=enes&in=ac_en&lf=en#result-sig-61618325-0) se propone la traducción **gusto**:

> I bought myself an ice cream as or for a treat
>
> me compré un helado para darme (un) gusto

Se podría también asociar con la siguiente entrada en el DLE:

> [**gusto**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Juk3i3t)
>
> 11. m. Capricho, antojo, diversión.

Comment: Pues irónicamente me gusta más "capricho", que aparece en la definición de la RAE para "gusto". Recoge muy bien la noción de que es algo especial pero innecesario. Aunque quizás sólo funcione para personas; lo de darle un capricho al perro no lo veo xD

Answer (score 3):

Si estoy hablando con un niño, voy a expresar esta idea así:

> Tengo **un regalito** para tí. / Te compré un regalito.

O bien:

> Tengo **algo especial** para tí. / Hice algo especial.

Los dos funcionan para el ejemplo del perro también.

Pero tu frase "This type of sausage, *chorizo*, is a special treat for our family" sería un poco diferente.  Sorry, I just looked back and realized the question was written in English so forgive me if I switch gears at this point.  Anyway, in the context you described, we could say

> El chorizo es un **plato especial** en mi casa, reservado para ocasiones especiales.

By the way, if you want to clarify that the *regalito* is something edible, especially something sweet, you could add *es muy rico*:

> Tengo un regalito para tí en el coche.  Ven a ver.  Es algo muy rico.

(I don't know if *rico* is a Mexicanism.)

Comment: I have certainly heard _rico_ in Spain

Answer (score 2):

Así, a bote pronto:

[**Manjar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OErwq5c)

> 2. m. Comida exquisita.

[**exquisitez**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HLnSGbm)

> 2. f. Cosa exquisita, especialmente un manjar de reducido tamaño y de aspecto y sabor delicados.

[**ambrosía**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2IEBMQ2)

> 1. f. Mit. Manjar o alimento de los dioses.
> 2. f. Vianda, manjar o bebida de gusto suave o delicado.

Answer (score 2):

[**Gollería**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JJ1cBoV)

> 1. f. Manjar exquisito y delicado.